# The data_out value is updating in the next clock edge which is supposed to update as soon as b is assigned, why?

Tags: verilog

```
    module memory(data_out,address,data_in,write_enable,clk,cs,rst);
        output  [3:0] data_out;
        input [3:0] address;
        input [3:0] data_in; 
        input write_enable;
        input clk;
        input cs;
        input rst;

    reg [3:0] data_out,b;
    reg [3:0] memory [0:15];
    reg [3:0] temp,a;



    always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
       if(rst) begin
         temp<=4'b0000;
         data_out<=4'b0000;
       end
       else 
       begin
         temp<=a;
         data_out<=b;
       end
       end


    always @(posedge clk)begin
       if(cs==1'b1) begin
            if (write_enable==1'b1) begin
                memory[address] <= data_in;
                a<=data_in;
             end
             else begin
               b<=memory[address];
             end
        end
    end

   endmodule
```

Comment: Your code says that `data_out` should be updated when there is a positive edge on `clk` or on `rst`. Why do you think it should change when `b` changes?

Comment: Showing a timing diagram generated  by your simulation might help us to uderstand your question better.

Comment: You are updating `data_out` and `b` simultaneously on `posedge clk` which means at every positive edge of `clk`, `data_out` will be assigned the value of `b` and `b` will be assigned the `memory[address]`, therefore `data_out` is assigned the old value of `b`.

Comment: this is the simulation results of my code.dont care condition on data_out signal..please do help me with this problem

Answer (score 3):

You are updating `data_out` and `b` simultaneously on `posedge clk` which means at every positive edge of `clk`, `data_out` will be assigned the value of `b` and `b` will be assigned the `memory[address]`, therefore `data_out` is assigned the old value of `b`

To get correct results, you can do this:

Do not update `data_out <= b` in first `always` block
Instead assign `data_out <= memory[address]` inside second `always` block itself.

Comment: but i have read that using assign inside an always block is not a good coding pratice.And also i have the same problem with temp in the 1st always block.If i remove both signals then my reset condition will not have an else statement.Will it synthesize into a proper RAM???sorry i am not an experienced programmer.help me out with my mistakes

Comment: @user34003 : In that case, you can remove the second `always` block and write its contents in the `else` of first `always` block.

Comment: @user34003 : I didn't mean to say, use `assign` statement, what I meant was write this statement in second `always` block: `data_out <= memory[address]`.